# How to check "Is landscape orientation allowed by user in iOS?"?

Tags: ios, swift

Question is clear at title I think. I am asking how to get "is landscape orientation locked or allowed by user from settings" currently. (like enable disable wifi or gps). Also, how to listen enable/disable action performed by user at settings?

I am not asking for orientation change listener (viewWillTransition) or current orientation state (UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape).

My aim is that if landscape orientation is disabled from settings of phone by user, a button will be visible to change video orientation manually, otherwise button will be invisible and video rotation will be fired only from real rotation of phone (viewWillTransition).

I tried to explain my question in detail because when I googled there are so many questions about (viewWillTransition) and (UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape). No answer found for my question.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible, the lock is handled by the OS and is transparent to the app.